# How can I encode data to json?

Tags: php, json

I want to encode data to json. Now by bottom code I have id and product title, but I want add another data like cost. How can I do that?

```
<?php

$sql = 'SELECT id,title,cost,cat
        FROM prodcts_df';
$q = $db->query($sql);
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>

 <?php
 while ($r = $q->fetch()): ?>
    <?php $myJson->$r['id']= $r['title'];?>
 <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php echo json_encode($myJson); ?>
```

Comment: Looks like you already did that on the last line

Comment: @Andreas yes but I can just show title. I need to show another data like cost or cat..

Comment: `Fetchall` and `json_encode` the whole result set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add cost in your array before json_encode like this:

```html
 // ......
 while ($r = $q->fetch()) { 
    $myJson->$r['id']= [
       'title' => $r['title'],
       'cost'  => $r['cost'],
       //.....
    ];
 }
// .....
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be better off just adding the whole row (`$r`) to the array rather than just the title.  You should also initialise the array (`$myJson`) first...

```
$sql = 'SELECT id,title,cost,cat
        FROM prodcts_df';
$q = $db->query($sql);
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Initialise array
$myJson = []
while ($r = $q->fetch()) {
    // Add the row to the array indexed by the ID
    $myJson[$r['id']]= $r;
}

echo json_encode($myJson);
```

Note that I use `$myJson[$r['id']]` instead of `$myJson->$r['id']` to add it in, this is more common when indexing lists of data like this.

If you only want parts of the array...

```
$myJson[$r['id']]= [ 'title' => $r['title'], 'cost' => $r['cost']];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
json_encode($myJson);
```

will encode your object in to JSON.
if you add additional data into the $myJson variable, it will include that in the output:

```
$myJson['foo'] = 'bar';
```